# ol.interaction.Draw deleteCondition not working with Point feature

Tags: openlayers

I'm not able to delete a point no matter which condition I write in deleteCondition.
It works with LineString and Polygon but not with Point features.

My version of OpenLayers is 3.19.1

Here is an excerpt of the code I'm using (it's TypeScript in Angular2 btw):

```
private _drawnFeatures: ol.Collection<any> = new ol.Collection<any>();

this._drawingSource = new ol.source.Vector({ features: this._drawnFeatures, wrapX: false });

this._drawingLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: this._drawingSource
});

this._drawInteraction = new ol.interaction.Draw({
    features: this._drawnFeatures,
    type: type,
    freehandCondition: ol.events.condition.altKeyOnly
});

var modify = new ol.interaction.Modify({
    features: this._drawnFeatures,
    deleteCondition: evt => { return ol.events.condition.shiftKeyOnly(evt) && ol.events.condition.singleClick(evt) }
});
```

Comment: You might get more help if you put this in jsFiddle or similar.

Comment: Did you get any solution?

Comment: 6 years after I'm afraid I don't remember  this @NicolasBoisteault.  Sorry but I can't help

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution :

```js
const modify = new Modify({
    deleteCondition: evt => {
        if (evt.type === 'singleclick' && altKeyOnly(evt)) {
            const features = map.getFeaturesAtPixel(evt.pixel, {
                layerFilter: layer => {
                    return layer === layerCandidate;
                },
                hitTolerance: 5
            });
            doSomething(features);
        }
    }
});
```